# Создание эквалайзера на PySide2

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qtimer, paintevent

Искал везде в интернете, не могу разобраться с `QtMultimedia` и `QtCharts.QBarSeries()`.

Мне нужно создать чарт и вставить его в аудиоплеер, чтобы при проигрывании была анимация чарта, т.е. **`мне нужен эквалайзер`**.

Comment: Возможно, я не правильно выразился. Мне нужен эквалайзер))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import random
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets   # !!!
#from PySide2.QtCore import Qt                  # !!!
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Equalizer_Bars(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, bars, steps, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # это соответствует размеру в области эквалайзера
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding
        )

        if isinstance(steps, list):
            # список цветов.
            self.n_steps = len(steps)
            self.steps = steps

        elif isinstance(steps, int):
            # int количество баров, по умолчанию синий.
            self.n_steps = steps
            self.steps = ['blue'] * steps
        else:
            raise TypeError('переменная шагов установлена неправильно, попробуйте с помощью списка или int')

        # создать bars
        self.set_bars = bars
        # определить настройки баров
        self.set_space_between_bars = 1
        self.set_height_of_bars = 1
        # установить цвет фона
        self.set_background_color = QtGui.QColor('white')
        # установить отступ по пикселю
        self.set_padding = 10  

        # create timer 
        self.set_timer = None
        # установить затухание для баров движения
        self.set_decay_frequency_ms(76)
        self.set_decay_value = 10

        # установить значения для minim and maxim 
        self.set_min_value = 0
        self.set_max_value = 100

        # сохранить все текущие значения в списке.
        self.set_all_values = [0.0] * bars

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        # create painter
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        # создать brush для рисования
        brush = QtGui.QBrush()
        brush.setColor(self.set_background_color)
        brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
        rect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, painter.device().width(), painter.device().height())
        painter.fillRect(rect, brush)

        # установить canvas
        d_height = painter.device().height() - (self.set_padding * 2)
        d_width = painter.device().width() - (self.set_padding * 2)

        # установить bars
        step_y = d_height / self.n_steps
        bar_height = step_y * self.set_height_of_bars
        bar_height_space = step_y * (1 - self.set_space_between_bars) / 2

        step_x = d_width / self.set_bars
        bar_width = step_x * self.set_space_between_bars
        bar_width_space = step_x * (1 - self.set_height_of_bars) / 2

        for i in range(self.set_bars):
            # вычисление позиции y для этого бара для остановки, из значения в диапазоне.
            c = (self.set_all_values[i] - self.set_min_value) / (self.set_max_value - self.set_min_value)
            n_steps_to_draw = int(c * self.n_steps)
            for n in range(n_steps_to_draw):
                brush.setColor(QtGui.QColor(self.steps[n]))
                rect = QtCore.QRect(
                    self.set_padding + (step_x * i) + bar_width_space,
                    self.set_padding + d_height - ((1 + n) * step_y) + bar_height_space,
                    bar_width,
                    bar_height
                )
                painter.fillRect(rect, brush)
        painter.end()

    def _trigger_refresh(self):
        self.update()

    def set_decay_trick(self, f):
        self.set_decay_value = float(f)

    def set_decay_frequency_ms(self, ms):
        if self.set_timer:
            self.set_timer.stop()
        if ms:
            self.set_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
            self.set_timer.setInterval(ms)
            self.set_timer.timeout.connect(self.set_decay_beat)
            self.set_timer.start()

    def set_decay_beat(self):
        self.set_all_values = [
            max(0, v - self.set_decay_value)
            for v in self.set_all_values
        ]
        self.update()                         # Перерисовать новую позицию.

    def size_values(self, v):
        self.set_all_values = v
        self.update()

    def values(self):
        return self.set_all_values

    def set_range(self, vmin, vmax):
        assert float(vmin) < float(vmax)
        self.set_min_value, self.set_max_value = float(vmin), float(vmax)

    # будет использоваться с QBrush
    def setColor(self, color):
        self.steps = [color] * self._bar.n_steps
        self.update()

    def set_color_bars(self, colors):
        self.n_steps = len(colors)
        self.steps = colors
        self.update()

    def set_bar_padding(self, i):
        self.set_padding = int(i)
        self.update()

    def set_bar_solid_percent(self, f):
        self._bar_solid_percent = float(f)
        self.update()

    def set_background_color(self, color):
        self.set_background_color = QtGui.QColor(color)
        self.update()


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.equalizer = Equalizer_Bars(8, \
        ['#00405e', '#3350a1', '#386787','#0088ba','#3396e6', '#00b9d0','#c1f9f9', '#cce2f7'])
        self.setCentralWidget(self.equalizer)

        self.set_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.set_timer.setInterval(100)                    
        self.set_timer.timeout.connect(self.update_values)
        self.set_timer.start()

    def update_values(self):
        self.equalizer.size_values([
            min(100, i+random.randint(0, 500) if random.randint(0, 10) > 2 else i)
            for i in self.equalizer.values()
        ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромная благодарность!

Comment: А как Вы его встроили в шаблон QtDesigner?

Comment: @ProBuro Если у вас есть вопрос - задайте его. В правом верхнем углу есть кнопка `Задать вопрос`, нажимайте ее и вперед. Не забудьте показать код, который у вас есть, написать что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Красиво выглядит :)